# Keep submenu while moving mouse

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to make a menu (with submenu and div containing link for every submenu on hover).

Something like this:

```
AAAA | BBBB
     | bbb1
     | bbb2   HERE IS MOUSE (bbb2 LINK)
     | bbb3
```

It is possible to keep listing submenus when you try to open link? If you move mouse from "bbb2" link disappear.

what I have now:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/yRu7U.png
and what I want:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/6NSbG.png

Here is JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zu8Eu/

Hope you understand. Thanks!

Comment: Change your HTML (and CSS) so that the links are children of the `<li>` elements.

Comment: @Blazemonger Isn't that easy have you tried with the fiddle he provides? http://jsfiddle.net/zu8Eu/6/

Comment: It's not trivial, no, but it's the best way -- by making the links children of the `<li>` tag, the hover event is maintained when you move the mouse over to it.

Comment: Check my fiddle i do that .... @Blazemonger if the block has absolute position but isn't next to the li the space between isn't considered the `li`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As is noted you may need to nested the `<div>` inside the `li` elements. But additional to keep the `hover()` you can use `padding` to set the white space:

HTML

```
<li id="submenu1">
  <a href="#" title="submenu1">aaaa1</a>
  <div class="one">
    <a href="1.html">Link for aaa1</a>
  </div>
</li>
```

CSS

```
.one {
display: none;
position: absolute;
top: 0px;
left:100%;
}
```

The demo **http://jsfiddle.net/zu8Eu/27/**

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure the are jQuery plugins that will provide you with what you want to achieve, but I'd say restructure you HTML and nest the elements properly.

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Menu 1</a>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Submenu 1</a>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Subsub menu</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

This way, you can use CSS to achieve what you want:

```
ul li ul{
  display: none;
}
ul li:hover > ul{
  display: block;
}
ul li ul li:hover > ul{
  display: block;
}
```

Once you hover on the first li, it will show the direct child ul, if you hover on that ul, it will still count as a hover on the first li, meaning it'll still be visible.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/x54gZ/

Comment: @Danko - My fiddle is as basic as it gets, he should be able to read it and change his code. Instead of someone else spoon-feeding him the code, he might even learn something from his question.

Comment: yep is a good aproach but if you apply this on his fiddle you can see this isn't the total solution ... http://jsfiddle.net/zu8Eu/6/ if the block has absolute position but isn't right next to the li the space between isn't considered the `li`

Comment: How I can use same position for all links? `position: absolute;` isn't working here. I mean, is the same result.

Comment: @Danko - true, I did not take into account the absolute positioning and my 'solution' won't work in this case.